# How to turn a list of integers to integers only (python)

Tags: python, list, join, concatenation

Without using loops, is there any way to get a string of integers such as [88, 88, 88] into 88 88 88 (integers separated only by spaces)?

Comment: `' '.join(map(str,lst))` and note that int and space concatenation is not possible.

Comment: Your title says you have a list of integers, while your question says you have a string of integers. Which is it?

Answer (score 0):

You contradict yourself: at one point, you say you have a list of integers, and later, you say you have a string "[88, 88, 88]". Here's how to make both into your desired string.

**In case of list:**

`string = " ".join(list)`

Should suffice. The string method join() returns a string with all the elements in a list, separated by another string (in this case, " ").

**In case of string:**

```
import re
new_string = re.sub('[\[\]\,]', '', old_string)
```

Good ol' regex comes in handy.